# Differences between the mounts?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Is it the case that the only difference between the mounts in DA:I is aesthetic?  Is there at least a difference in function between the different *type* of mounts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Mounts page](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Mounts) of the DA wiki, the difference between the *type* of mounts is the number of melee hits your mount can take before throwing you off:

- Horses take one blow
- Harts take two blows
- Dracolisks take three blows
- Nuggalopes take four blows

Otherwise the differences seem to be aesthetic.

Answer (score 2):

Some mounts have more "health" than others, allowing you to take more damage before being thrown off. Other than this, the differences are largely cosmetic.